# How do I make my React state update immediately?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, immutability, create-react-app

The function I've made which purpose is to update state does not work perfectly.

I make a deep copy of my current state which I modify, then I set the state to that changed copy. I decided to run a simple map on the copy and update a property on each object in the array, this made the app update state immediately and show the changes. (not shown in the code below, something I just tried)

But it does not work with the modifications I truly want to make to the copy. Since the setState happens async, I understand that the changes don't happen immediately, how could I solve this? Because the changes are seen when the function is triggered a second time, but I want it to happen on the first run. You could see a live demo of what I'm building at https://non.mpedersen.me/ if you want.

Function in App.js

```
addressSearch(address){
    console.log('firing search for distance. Origin is: ' + address)
    let origin = [address];
    const newStores = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.stores))
    let service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();

    newStores.map(store => service.getDistanceMatrix({
      origins: origin,
      destinations: store.addressapi,
      travelMode: 'DRIVING',
    }, result => {
      store.distance = result.rows["0"].elements["0"].distance.text.replace(/\Dkm/, '').replace(/,/,'.').replace(/\s/, '');
      store.duration = result.rows["0"].elements["0"].duration.text;
    }))

    newStores.sort((a,b) => a.distance - b.distance);
    this.setState({stores : newStores})
  }
```

Comment: BTW, what's up with `const newStores = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.stores))`??? What's the point

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, I'm going to try your suggestion. I tried to make a deep copy with slice, but the new array ended up referencing the old. I did not want to mutate the state directly, therefore I wanted to work on an independent copy of the original state

Comment: Is that an object? you could do `const newStores = { ...this.state.stores }`.. 
That's a good reason to use `immutable.js` :)

Comment: It's an array containing objects :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved it :)

```
getDistanceMatrix = (address, store) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      let service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
      let origin = [address];
      service.getDistanceMatrix({
        origins: origin,
        destinations: store.addressapi,
        travelMode: 'DRIVING',
      }, result => {
        store.distance = result.rows["0"].elements["0"].distance.text.replace(/\Dkm/, '').replace(/,/,'.').replace(/\s/, '');
        store.duration = result.rows["0"].elements["0"].duration.text;
        resolve(store)
      })
    })
  }

  addressSearch(address){
    console.log('firing search for distance. Origin is: ' + address)
    const newStores = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.stores))
    Promise.all(newStores.map(store => this.getDistanceMatrix(address, store))).then(newStore => {
      newStores.sort((a,b) => a.distance - b.distance);
      this.setState({stores : newStores})
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

You must `setState` after all `getDistanceMatrix` are finished and your map is done. Because that function runs async, you are not really getting the function completion when you `setState`. The completion happens in another stack.

Promises are really good because they help dealing with scenarios like this. This is a really nice question because it shows the nature of JS mechanisms (event-loop).

Try this code but know that I haven't tested/runned it, if you get the idea it will get you to the right place:

```
  const getDistanceMatrix = (store) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      service.getDistanceMatrix({
        origins: origin,
        destinations: store.addressapi,
        travelMode: 'DRIVING',
      }, result => {
        store.distance = result.rows["0"].elements["0"].distance.text.replace(/\Dkm/, '').replace(/,/,'.').replace(/\s/, '');
        store.duration = result.rows["0"].elements["0"].duration.text;
        resolve(store)
      })
    })
  }

  addressSearch(address){
    console.log('firing search for distance. Origin is: ' + address)
    let origin = [address];
    const newStores = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.stores))
    let service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();

    Promise.all(newStores.map(getDistanceMatrix).then((newStores) => {
      newStores.sort((a,b) => a.distance - b.distance);
      this.setState({stores : newStores})
    })
  }
```

BTW, setting state asynchronously after a Promise is resolved may lead to errors if the host component is not mounted anymore. That's actually an excellent reason to adopt a pattern like redux, it simplifies things like this a lot!

Comment: I've planned to implement Redux, but first I want to understand how state works in React. I try to implement this but get an error saying: "ReferenceError: store is not defined. It's store thats begin passed as the first argument in the map function on the newStores array in the promise. I haven't used promises before, but I'm going to look into that. Why do you think I get that error and do you see how I could solve it?

Comment: Map should've got one argument: the function iterator. I edited my answer with the fix for the error you mentioned.

Comment: Shouldn't origin, newstores and service be declared inside of getDistanceMatrix?

Comment: You are right, it should.. The code was really just an idea of how to get it working.